# how to set the admin user with GAE dev app server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create an Admin-only page for my GAE application. But I found there's no way to set a Admin user, so I cannot log on the page I created and test the function. I tried the local Admin console, but no luck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google App Engine provides a pretty straightforward way to create a private admin section of your web application.

**1.**
In your `app.yaml`, any URL handler can have a login setting to restrict visitors to only those users who have signed in, or just those users who are administrators for the application.
If the setting is `login: admin`, once the user has signed in, the handler checks whether the user is an administrator for the application. If not, the user is given an error message; if the user is an administrator, the handler proceeds.
Here a snippet of app.yaml where the `/admin/.*` routes are admin restricted :

```
 - url: /admin/.*
   script: admin.py
   login: admin
```

**2.**
Trying to access the admin url, the dev app server automatically shows the login panel where you should check the **Sign in as Administrator** checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you log in (the blue box where you enter the email) there is a checkbox to apply the administrator flag to your session.

Answer (score 0):

You can define admin only pages in your app.yaml, like so:

```
- url: /secrets/
  script: /secrets/example.py
  login: admin
```

an admin is whoever is so defined in your appengine.google.com control panel, under permissions.